# "Two-pass algorithm" implementation in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, beginner, matrix

I'm rather new to Java and to algorithms in general. I implemented the so called [Two-pass algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling#Two-pass), and want to know if there are improvements to my way of implementing it. What it does is it takes a matrix of ones and zeros and replaces all ones by labels. All ones that are connected should be labeled with the same label. Each such component should have a unique label. The end result can be visualized by replacing each label with a color, like this:

[image: result]

I followed as closely as I could the pseudo-code available in [this section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling#Graphical_example_of_two-pass_algorithm) of the Wikipedia article. But are there improvements?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class MatrixComponents {

    public int[][] labeledMatrix;

    public MatrixComponents(int[][] matrix) {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> linked = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
        int[][] labels = new int[matrix.length][matrix[0].length];

        int NextLabel = 0;

        //First pass
        for(int i=0; i<matrix.length; i++) {
            for( int j=0; j<matrix.length; j++) {
                labels[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }

        for(int i=0; i<matrix.length; i++) {
            for(int j=0; j<matrix[0].length; j++) {
                if(matrix[i][j] != 0) {

                    //Labels of neighbors
                    ArrayList<Integer> neighbors = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                    for(int ni=-1; ni<=1; ni++) {
                        for(int nj=-1; nj<=1; nj++) {
                            if(i+ni<0 || j+nj<0 || i+ni>labels.length-1 || j+nj>labels[0].length-1) {
                                continue;
                            }
                            else {
                                if(i+ni == 0 && i+nj == 0) continue;
                                if(labels[i+ni][j+nj] != 0) neighbors.add(labels[i+ni][j+nj]);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if(neighbors.size() == 0) {
                        ArrayList<Integer> tempArrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                        tempArrayList.add(NextLabel);
                        linked.add(NextLabel, tempArrayList);
                        labels[i][j] = NextLabel;
                        NextLabel++;
                    }
                    else {

                        labels[i][j]=1000*1000;
                        for(int neighbor : neighbors) {
                            if(neighbor < labels[i][j]) labels[i][j] = neighbor;
                        }

                        for(int neighbor : neighbors) {
                            linked.set(neighbor,union(linked.get(neighbor),neighbors));
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        //Second pass
        for(int i=0; i<matrix.length; i++) {
            for(int j=0; j<matrix[0].length; j++) {
                ArrayList<Integer> EquivalentLabels = linked.get(labels[i][j]);
                labels[i][j]=1000*1000;
                for(int label : EquivalentLabels) {
                    if(label < labels[i][j]) labels[i][j]=label;
                }
            }
        }

        labeledMatrix = labels;
    }

    //union: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283047/intersection-and-union-of-arraylists-in-java
    public <T> ArrayList<T> union(ArrayList<T> list1, ArrayList<T> list2) {
        Set<T> set = new HashSet<T>();

        set.addAll(list1);
        set.addAll(list2);

        return new ArrayList<T>(set);
    }

    public int[][] getLabeledMatrix() {
        return labeledMatrix;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] matrix = {{0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
                0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0,
                1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0,
                1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
                0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
                0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0,
                0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 0,
                1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1,
                0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
                0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1,
                1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 0,
                0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
                1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0,
                0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1}, {0,
                0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1,
                0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0,
                1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
                0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 1,
                1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1,
                1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
                0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0,
                0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 1,
                1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1,
                1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
                1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1,
                1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0,
                1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1,
                0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {1,
                1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1,
                0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}};

        MatrixComponents matrixComponents = new MatrixComponents(matrix);
        int[][] newMatrix = matrixComponents.getLabeledMatrix();

        System.out.println("{");
        for(int i=0; i<newMatrix.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("{");
            for(int j=0; j<newMatrix[0].length; j++) {
                if(j != newMatrix[0].length-1)
                    System.out.print(newMatrix[i][j]+", ");
                else
                    System.out.print(newMatrix[i][j]);
            }
            if(i != newMatrix.length-1)
                System.out.println("},");
            else
                System.out.println("}");
        }
        System.out.print("}");
    }
}
```

The test in the main method prints the array. I don't know of any quick way of visualizing it in Java, but if it would be visualized it would look like my image above.

Comment: Technically initialization of the matrix doesn't count as a pass, so I would move `//First pass` to the beginning of the following for loop.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Declare by interface and not implementation

Instead of

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> linked = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
```

use:

```
List<List<Integer>> linked = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
```

Or, if you're using Java 7+:

```
List<List<Integer>> linked = new ArrayList<>();
```

Edit: When looking at your code a bit more, with all the `union` method and stuff going on, I wonder if it perhaps should be `List<Set<Integer>>` right from the start, so that you could use

```
linked.get(neighbor).addAll(neighbors);
```

instead of what you currently do:

```
linked.set(neighbor,union(linked.get(neighbor),neighbors));
```

---

Algorithmically speaking, this part:

```
//First pass
for(int i=0; i<matrix.length; i++) {
    for( int j=0; j<matrix.length; j++) {
        labels[i][j] = 0;
    }
}
```

Is a) Not part of the first pass. b) Totally unnecessary as the `labels` array is filled with zeros already. c) Buggy if `matrix` is not square.

---

```
int[][] matrix = {{0, 0, 0, 0, 1, ...
```

I'd highly recommend **reading from a file** instead of hardcoding into the code!

---

Your constructor and your main method is doing way too many things, break up the code into additional methods.

Some methods can include:

- Read matrix from file / some input / code
- One (or more) methods for doing the "first pass" (you can put the 2d outer loop in one method, which can call another method)
- One method for the "second pass"
- One method for the output

---

```
public int[][] labeledMatrix;
```

Don't use `public` fields like that, that one should be `private`. It's good to restrict the visibility as much as possible.

---

`i` and `j` vs. `x` and `y`

Sometimes 2d arrays are indexed as `matrix[x][y]` and sometimes as `matrix[y][x]`, to make it clear which version you're using, don't use `i` and `j`. I really don't like those variable names when using 2d arrays.

---

It is a good practice to always use braces, even for one-liners: (Even I get told this from time to time!)

```
if(i+ni == 0 && i+nj == 0) continue;
if(labels[i+ni][j+nj] != 0) neighbors.add(labels[i+ni][j+nj]);
```

Is changed to:

```
if (i + ni == 0 && i + nj == 0) {
    continue;
}
if (labels[i + ni][j + nj] != 0) {
    neighbors.add(labels[i + ni][j + nj]);
}
```

Remember the comments about the naming though.

---

For your drawing an image plans, you should read up on [Creating and Drawing to an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/drawonimage.html) and the chapter that follows it [Writing/Saving an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/saveimage.html). You can use the [`Graphics2D`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html) object as shown in the first link to draw rectangles on the image.

---

```
if(neighbors.size() == 0) {
```

is the same as

```
if (neighbors.isEmpty()) {
```

Answer (score 11):

**White-Space**

You really need some white-space in your code. This is the first thing that will help to read your code easily. I have not read a lot your since it's really to read those kind of exppresions :

> ```
> if(i+ni<0 || j+nj<0 || i+ni>labels.length-1 || j+nj>labels[0].length-1)
> ```

With some white-spaces, it will be easier to easily see what's going on.

```
if(i + ni < 0 || j + nj < 0 || i + ni > labels.length - 1 || j + nj > labels[0].length - 1)
```

It could look like it take a lot more of space, but it's worth it. Imagineiftosavespacewewouldallwritelikethis (This is just an exaggeration, this is not that much of a problem).

**Variables names**

I know `i` and `j` are common names for counter in a `for` loop, but you can give relevant names too. Why would you not follow the "suggestion" from the wiki and use `row` and `column`, this would be much more relevant to your context.

Reading `i + ni < 0` versus `row + neighborsPosition`, I prefer the second option.

In Java, variable names are `camelCase` so `EquivalentLabels` and `NextLabel` should be `equivalentLabels` and `nextLabel`. (Hint look at the coloration syntax in your question, it identify those variables like a class).

**Functions**

You could separate your code in smaller functions. A good example would be :

> ```
>                 ArrayList<Integer> neighbors = new ArrayList<Integer>();
>                 for(int ni=-1; ni<=1; ni++) {
>                     for(int nj=-1; nj<=1; nj++) {
>                         if(i+ni<0 || j+nj<0 || i+ni>labels.length-1 || j+nj>labels[0].length-1) {
>                             continue;
>                         }
>                         else {
>                             if(i+ni == 0 && i+nj == 0) continue;
>                             if(labels[i+ni][j+nj] != 0) neighbors.add(labels[i+ni][j+nj]);
>                         }
>                     }
>                 }
> ```

This clearly could be a function `constructNeighborsList`. It would not change your code much but would help read your code.

Comment: I'm looking at your algo, I will edit if I find something to say about it.

Comment: I would go a bit further with the methods. For example, `i+ni<0 || j+nj<0 || i+ni>labels.length-1 || j+nj>labels[0].length-1` could be extracted to method on its own, improving readability and promoting single purpose programming.

Comment: @Travis I almost suggest it, but I think he's not there yet. I agree with you though and I do it myself when the condition is complex. I might edit it when I'll be back home!

Answer (score 10):

Just a small little comment about your array initializer:

> ```
> int[][] matrix = {{0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
>         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0,
>         1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
>         1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
>         0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
>         0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0,
>         1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
>         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
>         0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
>         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0,
>         0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 0,
>         1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1,
>         0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
>         0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1,
>         1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 0,
>         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
>         1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
>         0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0,
>         0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1}, {0,
>         0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1,
>         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
>         0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0,
>         1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1,
>         0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
>         0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
>         1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 1,
>         1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1,
>         1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
>         0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0,
>         0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 1,
>         1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1,
>         1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
>         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
>         1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1,
>         1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0,
>         1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1,
>         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
>         0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {1,
>         1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1,
>         0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
>         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}};
> ```

Would be much easier to <s>read</s> *parse*, and to eventually maintain, if you put line breaks after each element, lining up each item:

```
int[][] matrix = {
       {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
       {1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, 
       {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
       {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0}, 
       {0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1}, 
       {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
       {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
       {1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1}, 
       {0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0},
       {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0}, 
       {1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1}, 
       {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
       {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
       {1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1}, 
       {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, 
       {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, 
       {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0}, 
       {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
       {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0}, 
       {0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0}, 
       {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
       {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
       {0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, 
       {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
       {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
       {0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, 
       {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
       {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0}, 
       {1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0}, 
       {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
};
```

Now whether or not it's a good idea to put *data* in your code like this, ... there *has to be* a better way... I'll leave the actual review to the [java](/questions/tagged/java) guys. Cheers!

Comment: Did you *have* to copy-paste that whole matrix into your answer? :)

Comment: What a troll - "just a small comment"... proceeds to paste two gigantic matrices.

Comment: +1. "A picture tells more than thousand words." "Show, don't tell" etc. I think's a perfectly valid answer, thanks.

Comment: @Pickett awesome! thanks! Welcome to the [CR voters' club](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Voters&filter=week) :D (looks like there's heavy caching on these pages though), feel free to spend up to 40/day, this site needs more voters! :)

Comment: This was bugging me too. I checked all the answers first to see if anyone had mentioned it yet. And alas someone did. +1

Answer (score 5):

Some small tips:

- Avoid calculations in a loop. Change `1000*1000` to a constant:

  ```
  public static final int MILLION = 1000 * 1000;
  ```
- Integer arrays have default value of zero when created, so your "first pass" could be arrested.

Comment: Much like no one would write `public static final int ONE = 1`, perhaps a better name for `MILLION` would be the significance of what it represents.  I would recommend `Integer.Max_Value` instead, as `MILLION` just seems arbitrary.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you. I did not understood the meaning by my self.

Comment: "Avoid calculations in a loop" is good advice in general, but in this case `1000 * 1000` is a compile-time constant and there's no performance implication. It's still a good idea for readability.

Comment: @ChrisHayes I agree with you in general, how ever I think it works slightly different. It's not a [compile constant](http://www.coderanch.com/t/454384/java/java/compile-time-constant) but it will optimized with Java jet. Of curse it doesn't meter in this case.

Comment: @Ilya_Gazman It absolutely is a compile-time constant, per your own link. In JLS terms, it's two primitive literals composed with the operator *, which is explicitly called out as a constant expression.

Comment: @ChrisHayes oh, OK. I misunderstood it at first. Good that I shared it with you ;)